# ¿Se pueden saber las tablas principales en una base de datos? (SQL SERVER)

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, server, datos

Estoy tratando de analizar una base de datos para saber de donde vienen los datos de un programa ya hecho para poder hacer una migración.
Necesito saber las tablas principales para empezar a trasladar la información desde esas tablas pero no tengo ni idea de como encontrarlas o si se puede hacer.
La base de datos tiene aproximadamente 1000 tablas , no tengo mucha experiencia en esto y no tengo idea de si lo que planteo sea posible o si pueden darme alguna idea para optimizar el análisis y trasladar la información.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Y cómo identificas cuáles son esas tablas principales de las 100 existentes?

Comment: ¿Cómo defines las tablas principales? Para hacer una migración hay que migrar todo o se puede perder información que luego será imposible recuperar.

Comment: ¿Qué dirías que es una _tabla principal_?, ¿qué la define como _principal_?

Comment: Concuerdo con las preguntas de jachguate, la deficion "Tabla principal" puede caer en muchos aspectos, las tablas pueden y no ser principales, eso depende del proceso que se vayan a ejecutar... por ejemplo una tabla que alberga informacion de un catalogo, tal vez alimenta un campo dropdown y es ahí cuando esta es la principal.